# How to reset(delete) CORS settings for a bucket? (GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cors, google-cloud-storage, bucket, gsutil

I wrote **the CORS settings** to **"cors.json" file** as shown below.

**"cors.json"**:

```json
[
    {
      "origin": ["http://localhost:8000"],
      "method": ["GET"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```

Then, run the command below to set **the CORS settings** to **my bucket** as shown below:

```
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://my-bucket
```

Now, how can I reset(delete) **the CORS settings**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write only **"[]"** to **"cors.json" file** as shown below:

**"cors.json"**:

```json
[]
```

Then, run the command below again to reset(delete) **the CORS settings of your bucket** as shown below:

```
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://my-bucket
```

Finally, if running the command below:

```
gsutil cors get gs://my-bucket
```

You will get this message below:

> gs://my-bucket/ has no CORS configuration.

In addition, for **"gsutil cors"**, there are only **"set"** and **"get"** as shown below:

```
gsutil cors set
```

```
gsutil cors get
```

So, for **"gsutil cors"**, there are no **"reset"** and **"delete"** as shown below:

```
gsutil cors reset # Doesn't exist
```

```
gsutil cors delete # Doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 2):

As of 2022, there is a command to clear the CORS configuration on a bucket.

```
gcloud storage buckets update gs://BUCKET_NAME --clear-cors
```

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors#disable-example